# Where can I find LDraw examples?

Tags: instructions, ldraw

Where can I find LDraw files to download?

I would like to have a collection of simple Lego examples and want to create step-by-step instructions for my youngsters.

Comment: Last time I checked, [the LDraw All-In-One installer](http://www.ldraw.org/article/104.html) comes with a bunch of sample official models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The models included in AIOI as mentionned by HaydenStudios is also available as [**separate download**](http://www.ldraw.org/downloads-2/downloads.html)
There is also a huge collection of LDraw models of official sets available on [**Eurobricks forum**](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=48285&#entry849700)